# MSBuild - The attribute "Text" in element <Message> is unrecognized

Tags: debugging, split, msbuild, output, target

So I have a .target file that is parsing through another .target file to grab build configuration information. an example of the markup it is trying to retrieve is:

```
<bldConfiguration>Debug|x64; Release|x64</bldConfiguration>
```

And the code that is performing the retrieval is:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <tempMap Include="$(bldConfiguration)"/>
        <Configs Include="@(tempMap)">
            <Configuration>$([System.String]::new('%(tempMap.Identity)').split("|")[0])</Configuration>
                <Platform>$([System.String]::new('%(tempMap.Identity)').split("|")[1])</Platform>
        </Configs>
    </tempMap>
</ItemGroup>
```

I get an error on the Platform property saying that the index is out of range. Based on ('%(tempMap.Identity)') the string that is getting split is Debug|x64 and Release|x64 so theoretically it shouldn't be out of range. If you see my error, feel free to correct me.

When I try to output the property contained within Configuration so I can see what the values are:

```
<Message Text="$([System.String]::new('%(tempMap.Identity)').split("|")[0])">
```

I get an error saying "The attribute Text in element  is unrecognized."

How do I "print" the  or  properties to the console or log in MSBuild so that I can see what the result is? I'm having a hard time debugging these markup .target files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I cite https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/5666#issuecomment-673773163

> It's possible that you would get an error trying to use Message and Text somewhere other than in a target.

(Same applies to <Warning> and <Error>)